# Kodeindb error, cant access my data object in my viewmodel

Tags: android, database, kotlin, kodein

i have a data class for store in db.

```
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class SavedCalculation(
    override val id: String,
    val model1: Model1,
    val model2: Model2
):org.kodein.db.model.orm.Metadata {    
}
```

```
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class Model1(
    var attr1: String = "",
    var attr2: String = "",
)
```

```
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class Model2(
    var attr1: String = "",
    var attr2: String = "",
)
```

if i call my savedCalculation object in my view model;

```
var saved = mutableStateOf<List<SavedCalculation>>(listOf())
        private set

fun load(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            useCases.load.invoke().collect { response ->
                when(response){
                    is Response.Loading -> {
                    }
                    is Response.Success -> {
                        saved.value = response.data
                        saved.value[0].model1 -> **this causes error.**
                    }
                    is Response.Error -> {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Error:

> Cannot access 'org.kodein.db.model.orm.HasMetadata' which is a supertype of 'com.myapp.data.model.SavedCalculationDto'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my main and data packages are seperate gradle build files, so kodeindb cant access dependencies from my view model.
i simply add same kodeindb dependencies in my build.gradle.kts, my problem solved.

```
//into viewmodel package gradle file:

implementation("org.kodein.db:kodein-db-jvm:0.8.1-beta")

implementation("org.kodein.db:kodein-db-serializer-kotlinx:0.8.1-beta")

implementation("org.kodein.db:kodein-leveldb-jni-jvm-windows:0.8.1-beta")

implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.2")
```